# Rails installation fails while running make nior4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m trying to install the current stable version of rails (5.2)

```
gem install rails
```

but it fails:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: /Users/ms1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/nio4r-2.1.0/ext/nio4r
[…]
compiling nio4r_ext.c
In file included from nio4r_ext.c:7:
./../libev/ev.c:488:48: warning: '/*' within block comment [-Wcomment]
/*#define MIN_INTERVAL  0.00000095367431640625 /* 1/2**20, good till 2200 */
                                              ^
./../libev/ev.c:1068:26: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') to 'unsigned int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
[…]
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
9 warnings and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [nio4r_ext.o] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
```

I’m on Mac OS X HighSierra (10.13.2) and I’ve installed Xcode (9.2) with developer / command-line tools (9.2), rvm 1.29.3, Homebrew 1.4.0, bundler 1.16.0, nokogiri 1.8.1.

I’m on ruby 2.4.1, but tried 2.4.2, 2.3.0, 2.2.2 as well, always with the same result.

Installing nio4r manually results in the same problem:

```
gem install nio4r
[…]
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Some answers on StackOverflow suggested

```
gem install nio4r -v '1.1.0' -- with-cflags="-std=c99"
```

which did not work, either.

Interestingly,

```
rails
```

gives me the following output on my machine:

```
Ignoring bigdecimal-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  
Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 1.3.2
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type: sudo gem install rails
```

Of course I tried both of the above mentioned hints, too; both result in the same problem as stated initially.

As I'm running out of ideas here and couldn't find any other helpful advice, I'm really looking forward for any ideas on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filing an [issue on nio4r's Github page](https://github.com/socketry/nio4r/issues/178) solved my problem: There was an old `port.h` file from an abandoned Postgres installation in `/usr/local/include/` on my system which was causing the trouble.

Removing `/usr/local/include/port.h` allowed me to install Rails!

Comment: I have the same error, but different log. wasted one whole day to resolve but no help.